# Custom wordpress post query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, api

I would like to query posts in a specific catergory and display the whole post on my Wordpress start page. I've already tried it with this piece of code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat'      => 3,
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);

query_posts( $args );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

instead of displaying the whole post, wordpress shows just the title of my posts.
what can I do to show the CONTENT of my posts instead of the title?

Comment: You would need to add `the_content()` (it might be `get_content()`) function within the `while` loop. I suggest not using a list if you show alll the content. Right now you're telling it to show the title only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo '<li>';
the_content();
echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

See [The Loop in Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) for reference